# What are all the keyboard/mouse controls in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a list of every keyboard control in Skyrim.  Bonus points for the mouse too.

Comment: Esc/Start -> controls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the default controls for the PC:

```
Mouse  Look/turn
W      Move forward
S      Move backward
A      Strafe left
D      Strafe right
C      Toggle Automove / Zoom item in inventory
Alt    Sprint
Shift  Walk (slower and quieter than default movement)
Space  Jump
Ctrl   Crouch/sneak mode
E      Equip also to Mount/Dismount Horses

R      Ready/sheathe weapon
LMouse  Attack with weapon or cast spell in right hand (primary hand maps to primary mouse)
RMouse  Attack with weapon or cast spell in left hand / Block if available
Z      Racial power/Dragon shout
P      Magic menu
Q      Favorites

E      Activate/use/hold to manipulate objects
F      Change views (1st and 3rd person)
Tab    Character Menu
J      Open journal
T      Wait
1-8    Hotkeys (no numpad)
M      Map
I      inventory
/      Perk menu
Mwheel  Scroll in menus or zoom while in 3rd person
Esc    Menu
`      Open/close the console (~ key)
```

Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Controls)

Comment: What is "automove"?

Comment: Character walks forward without the player holding W

Comment: and also caps lock toggles sneak/crouch on and off (useful if you want to sneak for a while and don't want to hold down shift the whole time)

Comment: what is hotkeys?

Comment: @JimThio They're basically shortcuts. In this case, you can assign a weapon, shield, or spell to 1-8, so that when you press that number, you equip whatever you assigned.

Answer (score 6):

F5 performs a quick save and F9 performs a quick load as well.
Left Mouse is by default your primary hand(right hand) and Right Mouse is the secondary hand (left hand) which can be confusing.